# is it safe to use the same variable name repeatedly in a series of functions?

Tags: python, try-except, variable-names

Is it safe to re-use the same variable name repeatedly in a series of functions? My code is:

```
with open(thisdoc_dir + '/' + 'metadata.txt', 'w') as m:
    m.write(str(metadatas[1]) + '\n')
    m.close()
    
with open(thisdoc_dir + '/' + 'metadata.json', 'w') as m:
    m.write(str(metadatas[0]))
    m.close()
    
with open(thisdoc_dir + 'toc.txt', 'w') as m:
    m.write(str(metadatas[2]))
    m.close()
```

Before this block, I try/except to test for successful creation of `thisdoc_dir` and `metadatas`.  Is there anything else that can be a gotcha?

Comment: Yup, totally safe.  I prefer reusing names that have short scopes, actually, because it reduces the number of different variables to keep track of when I'm reading the code; there's no way a stale value is going to unexpectedly resurface because of a typo.

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need to explicitly close files opened using `with`.

Comment: Where are the functions? Maybe you mean "function calls"? Or are you referring to the `with`-`as` statements?

Comment: You're asking about the name `m`, right? I'm just confused why you mention that you check for successful creation of `thisdoc_dir` and `metadatas`, cause if they weren't successfully created, the lines that use them would raise exceptions (like `FileNotFoundError` and `IndexError`, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't functions, but rather context managers. Regardless, `m` is overridden each time. Also, since you are using with, you don’t need to manually close the file afterwards.